# What is the Weil-Petersson metric of the moduli space of elliptic curves?

Tags: complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces, teichmueller-theory

One can define the Weil-Petersson metric on the moduli space of Riemann surfaces. I would like to know an explicit example of such a metric. What is the Weil-Petersson metric of the moduli space of elliptic curves (which can be thought of a punctured sphere or the upper half plane)?

Comment: It seems to me that one cannot really define the Weil-Petersson metric on the moduli space of elliptic curves, because this requires at least 2 independent quadratic diffrentials or equivalently holomorphic automorphic forms with respect to the corresponding fuchsian group -which exists for genus at least 2. So there has been an ad hoc WP metric defined for instance in Imayoshi and Taniguchi's An introduction to Teichmüller spaces. They use a quasiconformal mapping and the Beltrami coefficient but being incompetent i don't get why this should be called WP. It yields the usual Poincaré metric.

Comment: Let's note that the expression in terms of Fenchel-Nielsen coordinates only exists for genus at least 2. The volume of the Poincaré half-plane is infinite while for the other Teichmüller spaces it is finite and this is used to easily do probability on complex curves and their complex structures; this is an area of research where important results have been obtained recently.

Answer (score 0):

So, if I understand you correctly, let $S = T^2$ be the real torus of dimension 2. You are wondering what the Weil-Petersson metric is on the moduli space of complex structures ${\cal M}(S)$.

The Teichmüller space of $S$ denoted ${\cal T}(S)$ can naturally be identified with the upper half-plane $\mathbb{H}^2$. Under this identification, the Weil-Petersson metric on ${\cal T}(S)$ is just the hyperbolic metric on $\mathbb{H}^2$. I have to confess, I don't know what is the simplest way to see that this is true.

Then the moduli space ${\cal M}(S)$ is the modular curve $\mathbb{H}^2 / SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$, an the Weil-Petersson metric there is just the induced hyperblic metric on the quotient.

I hope I did not say anything wrong (and answered your question), some people would be far more competent than me to answer this.